# Как изменить порядок отображения блоков в табличной верстке?

Tags: html, css, табличная-верстка

Нужно сверстать адаптивный имейл. Возникла проблема с отображением секции на мобильных устройства. Как сделать так, чтобы на мобильных устройствах блок с текстом отображался выше картинки?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>$ {MessageSubject}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

        html {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        }

        a {
            color: #1978CD;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        @media (max-width:480px) {
            .banner-title {
                font-size: 34px;
                line-height: 36px;
            }
        }

        @media screen {

            /* hides this rule from unsupported clients */
            .webfont {
                font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
               <table width="600" align="center">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-right:0; padding-left:0; margin:0px;">
                        <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
                    style="width:100%; max-width:600px; border:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table bgcolor="#f6f6f6" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                style="background-color: #f6f6f6;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"
                                        style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 25px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; color: #ffffff">
                                        <div class="column"
                                            style="width:100%;max-width:270px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                                >
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 12px;"><img
                                                            src="https://i.ibb.co/ZXgjm7p/Rectangle-1.pngg"
                                                            alt="Picture"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="column"
                                            style="width:100%;max-width:270px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                                >
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="webfont" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: bold;
                                                    font-size: 24px;
                                                    line-height: 29px; 
                                                    color: #222222;
                                                    ">
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="webfont" style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: normal;
                                                    font-size: 16px;
                                                    line-height: 24px;
                                                    color: #222222;
                                                    ">
                                                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" ID="Table5" Border=0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by:
                                            <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%,
                                            %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr> -->
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: С таблицами никак.

Comment: @nazarpunk вы не правы, друже

Comment: @highpassion с учётом того, что это вёрстка для `email`?

Comment: @nazarpunk https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex

Comment: @nazarpunk смотря для какого почтового клиента

Comment: @highpassion почтовые клиенты не сильно спешат flex поддерживать.

Comment: @nazarpunk у apple mail, mail.ru, protonmail всё с этим в порядке, очень странно, что такие гиганты как Gmail и MS Outlook отстают  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что самый жизнеспособный вариант — это медиазапросы + padding + background-position (если сделать картинку фоном). Все остальные трюки, включая direction:rtl, display:table-footer-group, как и флекс-лейауты имеют очень ограниченную поддежку в популярных почтовых сервисах. Так что вопрос, стоит ли оно того...

Answer (score 1):

Я добавил вашему элементу `td` идентификатор `runner`, но можно и присвоить класс, и прописал для свойства `flex`-контейнера для расположения его дочерних элементов.

Вам потребуется добавить правило для `#runner` в медиа-запросе.

[Статья о медиа-запросах на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

О модуле `CSS Flex` вы можете почитать на:

[Flex на MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

[Полный гайд по Flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

**UPD: для Gmail и Yahoo! Mail этот код не будет валиден**

```css
#runner {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>$ {MessageSubject}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">
    <style>
        @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');

        html {
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
            -ms-text-size-adjust: none;
        }

        a {
            color: #1978CD;
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        p {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        @media (max-width:480px) {
            .banner-title {
                font-size: 34px;
                line-height: 36px;
            }
        }

        @media screen {

            /* hides this rule from unsupported clients */
            .webfont {
                font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif !important;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
               <table width="600" align="center">
                  <tr>
                     <td style="padding-top:0; padding-bottom:0; padding-right:0; padding-left:0; margin:0px;">
                        <![endif]-->
                <table align="center" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"
                    style="width:100%; max-width:600px; border:0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table bgcolor="#f6f6f6" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                style="background-color: #f6f6f6;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td id="runner" align="center"
                                        style="padding-bottom: 25px; padding-top: 25px; padding-left: 25px; padding-right: 25px; color: #ffffff">
                                        <div class="column"
                                            style="width:100%;max-width:270px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                                >
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td align="center" style="padding-bottom: 12px;"><img
                                                            src="https://i.ibb.co/ZXgjm7p/Rectangle-1.pngg"
                                                            alt="Picture"></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="column"
                                            style="width:100%;max-width:270px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
                                            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"
                                                >
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="webfont" style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: bold;
                                                    font-size: 24px;
                                                    line-height: 29px; 
                                                    color: #222222;
                                                    ">
                                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="webfont" style="font-style: normal;
                                                    font-weight: normal;
                                                    font-size: 16px;
                                                    line-height: 24px;
                                                    color: #222222;
                                                    ">
                                                        Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!-- <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" ID="Table5" Border=0>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <font face="verdana" size="1" color="#444444">This email was sent by:
                                            <b>%%Member_Busname%%</b><br>%%Member_Addr%% %%Member_City%%,
                                            %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%, %%Member_Country%%<br><br>
                                        </font>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile">Update Profile</a></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr> -->
                </table>
                <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
      <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Это всё правильно, конечно, но тут вопрос был про верстку письма. Предложили бы вариант, который работает хотя бы в Gmail: https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=flex, но о gmail никто не спрашивал

Comment: Mail.ru не поддерживает `flex-direction: column-reverse`, так что в реальности статистика гораздо хуже :(

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov не пробовали поменять элементы местами? :)

Comment: я ничего сам не пробовал в контексте вопроса пользователя, просто вижу что ваш ответ не валидный для Mail.ru и Gmail

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov почему вы так уверены, что Mail.ru не поддерживает `column-reverse`? если это так, то я допишу, что нужно переставить элементы и указать `flex-direction: column` для поддержи mail.ru

Comment: Они сами ссылаются сюда как на наиболее полный список https://www.caniemail.com/clients/mail-ru/#desktop-webmail

Comment: @AlexeyVladimirov опять же не могу с вами согласиться, нигде явно не указано ничего про `column-reverse`, ни в Supported, ни Not Supported, ни в Partially Supported, а у mail.ru в разделе помощь -> Письма не увидел никакой инфы ) добавил ваши уточнения в ответ, спасибо )

Comment: я ориентировался на этот официальный help https://help.mail.ru/developers/design/css + показалось странным, что на caniemail указана поддержка конкретно flex-direction: column, а не св-ва  flex-direction в целом. Но вы правы, по факту column-reverse работает. Проверил в новом веб-интерфейсе и iOS-приложении. Проблема только с Gmail — он оставляет display:flex, но убирает все flex-свойства. Т.е. делает хуже, ставя блоки жестко в горизонтальный ряд на моб. экране (обычные блоки встали бы один под другим).